# how to get conflicts in sharpsvn.merge()

Tags: c#, svn, merge, conflict, sharpsvn

I am trying to merge my code into a targetPath using sharpSvn. I am writing the following code:

```
client.merge(targetPath,source_url,range)
```

It works successfully when there is no conflict but the merge does not occur if there is a conflict in a merge. I want to get a boolean variable from the code which tells me whether or not there is a conflict while merging the revision_id. Is there any way I can do this?

Edit :
I have been trying this by the following way

```
try
{
 String src = "source_url";
 String targetPath = "foo/bar";
 SvnRevisionRange range = new SvnRevisionRange(839071, 839072);
 SvnMergeArgs mergeArgs = new SvnMergeArgs();
 mergeArgs.DryRun = true;
 mergeArgs.Conflict += new EventHandler<SvnConflictEventArgs> 
 (Mergeargs_Conflict);
 mergeArgs.Force = false;
 bool result = client.Merge(targetPath, new SvnUriTarget(src), range, mergeArgs);
}
catch (SvnException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("conflict");
}
```

and the event is as follow:

```
static void Mergeargs_Conflict(object sender, SvnConflictEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I were called.");
}
```

But it is not giving me any output on the screen. I am trying to merge a url where I know a conflict exists as trying to merge from tortoise svn is giving me a conflict. Please help in this regard.

Comment: Meybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749137/sharpsvn-merge-not-working-returns-true-but-not-able-to-see-changes-in-code

Comment: Check the edit please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. The thing was to remove the `dry run` property from merge. Now my event is firing and then revert the changes if the event is fired.